# How do I get LaTeX to recognize Greek letters on babel?

Tags: babel, babel-greek

By inputting this here whenever I type \gr and type greek text it doesn't recognize any of the greek characters and shows an error ob that line on Overleaf.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{ucs}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[greek,english]{babel}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcommand{\en}{\selectlanguage{english}}

\newcommand{\gr}{\selectlanguage{greek}}


\title{start}
\author{}
\date{}


\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section*{Introduction}


\gr

τεστ



\end{document}
```

Comment: Try to get rid of both `\usepackage{ucs}`and `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`: Unicode has been standard for a few years now.

Comment: that works, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`\usepackage{ucs}` is no longer needed (and neither is `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`, but that's probably not the issue here). Compile without these packages.